Why is .NET MAUI platform specific XAML code compiled by .net?
I created platform specific XAML code in a single-project .NET 8 MAUI app.
The platform specific XAML code in the Android and iOS platform folders are as follows
- Platforms
-- Android
--- Views
---- Mypage.xaml

- Platforms
-- iOS
--- Views
---- Mypage.xaml

The reason is, that I use a proprietary nuget package in a single-project .NET MAUI app. That nuget does not support 'pure' .net which I need for my unit tests, it only supports .net-android and .net-ios.
The 'Mypage.xaml' refers to an xmlns that is only present on Android and iOS
xmlns:MyPackage="clr-namespace:x.y.z;assembly=foo"

When trying to compile with .net for my unit test I get these errors

[error]D:\a\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator\Platforms_Android_Views_Mypage.xaml.sg.cs(18,19):
Error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'MyPackage' could not be
found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
D:\a\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator\Platforms_Android_Views_Mypage.xaml.sg.cs(18,19):
error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'MyPackage' could not be found
in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
[D:\a\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0]

The app works just fine with Android and iOS.
Why is .net trying to compile the code in the platform folder?
